# Turbo Flask Multithreading Application Context

Tags: multithreading, flask

I am currently developing a flask webapp that continuously scans the local network in a background thread and I am using Turbo Flask to push the updated results in a request's view.

Everything works fine but now I am having trouble splitting the tasks in different modules using the flask application factory approach: whenever the scanning thread is executed I get an `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.` even when using `with current_app.app_context():` inside the thread function.

Here is my `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from turbo_flask import Turbo
import threading


# global libraries
turbo = Turbo()

def init_app():
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object('config.Config')

    # init plugins
    turbo.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        from . import control
        control.ctrl_init(turbo)

        @app.before_first_request
        def before_first_request():
            threading.Thread(target=control.ext_updater).start()

        return app
```

And this is my reduced `control.py`

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for, current_app
)
from turbo_flask import Turbo
import os, click, requests
import nmap

turbo = Turbo()

def ctrl_init(turboa):
    turbo = turboa

def ext_updater():
    # start thread constantly looking for external machines
    with current_app.app_context():
        while True:
            ping_guests()
            turbo.push(turbo.replace(render_template("external_machines.html"), 'guests'))

def ping_guests():
    # network scanning code ommited
```

I'm actually not sure how to properly start the thread with the application context, and I guess passing the `turbo` object to the `ctrl_init` function is also not a neat way but I'm a little lost here and would appreciate any help!

The error is first thrown at the `with current_app.app_context():` in `control.ext_updater` but also removing it throws the same error when calling `turbo.push`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it working passing the app object along with creating the updater thread:

```
def ext_updater(app, turbo):
with app.app_context():
    while True:
        ping_guests()
        turbo.push(turbo.replace(render_template("external_machines.html"), 'guests'))
```

And call it with `threading.Thread(target=control.ext_updater, args=(app, turbo)).start()`

However, why doesn't it work with `current_app` in the thread?

Comment: So is this an answer to your question? If so, remove the "However, why doesn't it work with current_app in the thread?" at the end. If you don't feel the question is answered, because you wish to use with current_app, then delete this and add information as an edit to your question that you seek a solution with current_app only.